# Adding a div class based on screen size using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a `div class="container` that I would like to add to `<div class="second-menu-it">` if the screen size is less than 959px:

Below is the code i am trying to use:

```
$(window).on('resize', function() {
if($(window).width() < 959) {
    $('.second-menu-it').addClass('container');


})
```

Comment: you say less than and use >  ??  I think it should be  <

Comment: Sorry my bad..i typed it out wrong. even with < it doesnt work

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/qfq80v8s/

Answer (score 3):

You forgot the `}` after the `addClass`

```
$(window).on('resize', function() {
    if($(window).width() < 959) {
        $('.second-menu-it').addClass('container');
    }
});
```